# Deprecating Django Migrations

Tags: python, django

I have a long-maintained and large Django project with hundreds and hundreds of migration files at this point. The tests are taking a really long time to run now due to just how many migrations there are to run through before tests begin.

I'm wondering if there's a best-practice for deprecating existing migrations and starting fresh, perhaps with the old migration files archived on git but deleted from the working branch, and starting fresh with new 0001's based on the current schema.

We've luckily almost never had to roll back – and when we do it's at deploy time and not at some point down the line. Does anyone have any thoughts on what the process for starting migrations fresh on an existing project looks like?

Comment: Is there is a specific reason to deprecate migrations? Topological sorting happens in *O(n)*, so a lot of migrations will normally do not have much impact.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem things like tests just get set up really slow, much slower than imo they need to be if we aren't using the historical migrations. Is there a reason to keep migrations all the way back?